# Pip can't confirm SSL certificate

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, ssl-certificate, paramiko

I am having trouble installing paramiko on one system.  This same command worked earlier, but then something changed and I had reinstall Python, and now paramiko will not install. I am using Windows 7 with Python 3.6.4.
Pip returns the following error:

```
C:\Users\me>pip --trusted-host pypi.python.org install paramiko
Collecting paramiko
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/paramiko/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement paramiko (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for paramiko
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: what command you used to install? whats the python version?

Comment: If anyone can tell me how to format a code block, I would appreciate it.  I indented some of the above lines by 4 spaces as recommended, but it didn't work.

Comment: Use formatting tools select text and click **{ }** icon or **Ctrl+k**

Comment: What does `pip --version` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Paramiko [installation](http://www.paramiko.org/installing.html) documentation :

Versions supported :

- Python 2.7
- Python 3.4+

Looks like you are using incompatible version of Python

```
C:\Users\User>python -V
Python 3.6.4
```

Installation

```
pip3 install paramiko
```

or

```
pip install paramiko
```

**SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED** can be caused by pip [issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4205) or [python issue on Mac](https://bugs.python.org/issue29065)

Please upgrade pip to latest version for the same.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

After this issue should be resolved

Or try installing incremental

```
pip install incremental
```

Comment: I am using Python 3.6.4

Comment: Python 3.6 is surely above 3.4.

Comment: use `pip3 install paramiko` not `pip --trusted-host pypi.python.org install paramiko`

Comment: Great! That's because may be you have both python 2 and python 3 installed. Using pip3 will point it to python 3 interpreter.

Answer (score 33):

Using following commands helped me. please try this

1. For upgrading pip

`python -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --upgrade pip`

2. For installing new packages, eg numpy, pandas etc.

`python -m pip install PACKAGE NAME --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org`

[image: Installing numpy package]

[image: Upgrade pip]

Comment: OMG - sooo many other answers in this area did not work but this did!!!

Comment: Nice to hear that!

Comment: Yours is the only one answer works for me. Thanks so much. BTW, do you know how to add those trust link permanently? It used to work well until today...

Comment: Oh, I just found the way to add those sites permanently, <code> python -m pip config set global.trusted-host "pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org pypi.python.org" </code>

Answer (score 0):

Additionally If you get stuck after collecting the package but at the installation you get this following error:

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\numpy'
> check the permissions.

Following alternation to the command worked just fine for me:

```
python -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --user numpy
```