# I cannot install any package using pip

Tags: python, installation, pip, package, using

I am trying to install packages in python using `pip install numpy`....and always ending up by this error:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/numpy/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))) - skipping

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy......
```

[image]
I have disabled my anti-virus ...and turned off my firewall..but still doesn't work!

Please help.....
Thanks in advance  :)

Comment: Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49327929/pip-cant-confirm-ssl-certificate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails with "connection error: \[SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED\] certificate verify failed (\_ssl.c:598)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+certificate+verify+failed+unable+to+get+local+issuer+certificate

Comment: That's Great it solved my prob :) ...tq so much...

Answer (score 0):

I
You can use this following command and it will download the particular dependency without any issues. Please specify the package name in the <package_name>. It works fine for me.

`pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org <package_name>`